# Why does ggplot not allow suppressing of messages generated by its geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggridges

The `geom_density_ridges` geom from the `ggridges` package created ridgelines, and if a bandwidth is not specified, it attempts to find a sensible value. It then uses the `base` R `message` function to report that value (see https://twitter.com/ClausWilke/status/921363157553172480).

The `base` R function `suppressMessages` function is designed to suppress such messages. For example, this code outputs a message:

```
message('This is a message');
```

And this code outputs nothing:

```
suppressMessages(message('This is a message'));
```

However, for some reason, the suppressing of messages seems, um, suppressed when this geom is added to a ggplot. The following code *does* still produce a message:

```
require('ggplot2');
require('ggridges');
suppressMessages(ggplot(Orange, aes(x=age,y=Tree)) + geom_density_ridges());
```

(Specifically, "`Picking joint bandwidth of 319`".)

Why is this? Does `ggplot` do something to ensure that messages come through regardless of the users' specification? Or is this actually sensible behavior that I just happen to not know about?

When generating RMarkdown reports, the chunk option `message` can be set to `message=FALSE`, which suppresses all messages at the rendering level. And since that's my use case, my problem is solved.

And as Claus Wilke, the author of the `ggridges` package, suggested, you can always set the `bandwidth` of manually to avoid the message (https://twitter.com/ClausWilke/status/921361195231215616).

But *why* doesn't `suppressMessages` suppress the message in the first place?

Is this expected behavior that I just happen to not know about?

Comment: I noticed in the documentation it states `suppressMessages evaluates its expression in a context that ignores all ‘simple’ diagnostic messages.` I wonder if the key term here is *simple*...

Comment: If you manually call `print` instead of letting the interpreter take care of that for you then `suppressMessages` does suppress the messages.  `suppressMessages(print(ggplot(Orange, aes(x=age,y=Tree)) + geom_density_ridges()))` At one point I understood this process a little better (how messages get passed and how suppressMessages works and all that) but I've long since forgotten some of the details so am looking forward to an actual response explaining the 'why'.

Comment: @Dason I think you got it. The messages aren't generated till you call `print()` on the object. If you just type a variable in the R console, R implicitly calls `print()` on that object and shows the result. If you you run `supressMessages(ggplot(...))`,  that's really the same as `print(supressMessages(ggplot(...)))` and there are no messages generated during building. You need `supressMessages(print(ggplot(...)))` to silence those during printing.

Comment: Ah, that's it! So calling the `ggplot(...)` statement does not print anything yet; `ggplot` just returns the resulting object, which is then accepted by `suppressMessages` and passed on, where R calls the associated `print` method which then triggers the `message`s. By forcing this `print` call to occur within the `suppressMessages` context, the printing of the `message`s is indeed suppressed. That actually makes sense. So this would qualify as a 'Why' in my book - if you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it. Or we wait for more, whatever you prefer :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `ggplot()`, that command doesn't actually draw a plot -- it creates a ggplot object. Only when that object is printed is a plot actually drawn. When you type an expression in the R console, the default behavior is to call `print()` on the result which is why it seems like `ggplot()` draws a plot.

Note that the warnings you are experiencing do not occur during the creation of the ggplot object; they occur during the printing of this object. So if you run

```
suppressMessages(ggplot(...))
```

that's essentially the same as

```
print(suppressMessages(ggplot(...)))
```

when running R in interactive mode. But since no messages are generated by `ggplot()`, nothing is suppressed and those messages still appear when the resulting object is printed. To suppress the messages created during printing, you need to wrap the actual `print()` statement with `suppressMessages()`.

```
suppressMessages(print(ggplot(...)))
```