# When showing a ggplot in a shiny app, how do I capture the ggplot warning that appears in the console, and display in the app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a simple app, below, that displays a ggplot. ggplot generates a warning in the console (see picture at bottom). I'd like to capture the warning, and display it in the app, under the plot.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("How do i output ggplot warnings? :("),
   mainPanel(
       plotOutput("my_plot_that_generates_warnings"),
       tags$br(),
       verbatimTextOutput(outputId='ggplot_warnings')
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    messages <- reactiveValues(ggplot_warning = 'How to capture warning and display it?')
    output$my_plot_that_generates_warnings <- renderPlot({
        tryCatch({

            ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
                geom_point() +
                geom_smooth()

        }, message = function(e) {
            messages$ggplot_warning <- e$message
        }, warning = function(e) {
            messages$ggplot_warning <- e$message
        }, error = function(e) {
            messages$ggplot_warning <- e$message
        })
    })

    output$ggplot_warnings <- renderPrint({
        cat(messages$ggplot_warning)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I assume the underlying problem has to do with lazy evaluation and the fact that the graph doesn't actually get rendered (and the warning generated) until after the `trycatch`. I can actually get the warning to appear in the `verbatimTextOutput` by wrapping ggplot call in a `print()`, but then of course the plot doesn't show up.

In my ignorance of the problem I've tried `force()` rather than `print()` but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the evaluate package (see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evaluate/index.html)? Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963132/8757228 you might save your warning into a variable first and then display it whereever you want independent of your plot output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `ggplot` it creates an object of type `ggplot`, as far as my understanding goes, internally, the messages aren't generated till you call `print()` on the object. There's an explanation on similar issue wrt messages so have a read [Why does ggplot not allow suppressing of messages generated by its geoms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850633/why-does-ggplot-not-allow-suppressing-of-messages-generated-by-its-geoms).

What we can do is explicitly print the `ggplot` and capture the messages

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("This is now fixed :)"),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("my_plot_that_generates_warnings"),
    tags$br(),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId='ggplot_warnings')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth()
  })

  dataerrors <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
      print(data())
    }, message = function(e) {
      return(e$message)
    }, warning = function(e) {
      return(e$message)
    }, error = function(e) {
      return(e$message)
    })
  })

  output$my_plot_that_generates_warnings <- renderPlot({
    data()
  })

  output$ggplot_warnings <- renderPrint({
    dataerrors()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: One issue seems to be capturing multiple messages and warnings. If, for example, there are NAs in my data, there are multiple warnings generated (for each column with NAs)... Only 1 warning is captured with the current solution. Additionally, the geom_smooth warning actually comes as a message. So if there are warnings *and* messages I will only get one of those.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: well, i "solved" it by using some stuff out out https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html


basically, i used `withCallingHandlers` and built up a list of all messages/warnings, but it is sloooowwwww.

Comment: If this is an issue, you can either switch to other charting library, such as `highcharter`, `dygraphs`, `rCharts`, `billboarder`, `plotly` or write your own error handling with `req` and `need`